# PHP while loop running all over my "mysql" table

Tags: php, html, database, mysqli

**Hello, I'm trying to run on 15 rows ONLY! each time.**

First, this is my code-

PHP:

```
<div id ="items">
    <?php
    include './DateBaseLogOn.php';
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM items LIMIT 0, 15";
    $RESULT=$conn->query($sql);
    if(!$conn) {
      die("Connection Failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    $row = $RESULT->fetch_assoc();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($RESULT))
    {
    echo "<div id =\"itembox\">";
    echo "<div id=\"itempicture\"><img src=\"getImage.php?id=."$row['id']".\" width=\"230\" height=\"140\" /></div>";
    echo "<div id=\"iteminfo\">"."Info:".$row['info'].
    "</br>"."Current price:".$row['price'].
    "</br>"."Time until expired:".$row['exp'].
    "</br>"."Offer avilable until:".$row['timeleft'].
    "</br>"."Place:".$row['location'].
    "</div>";
    echo "<button class=\"sendprice\" onclick=\"location.href=$link\">Place bid</button>";
    echo "</div>";
    }
```

**My questions are:**

**1.** I'm getting an error :

`( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$row' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp\www\index.php on line 87`

If i delete the `<img src=\"getImage.php?id=."$row['id']".\" width=\"230\" height=\"140\" />`

it works but i need to put the image there...

**2.** how can i tell the while loop to run only on 15 rows? and how can i make it run on the next 15 row with a click of a button (look at the echo row before the last echo row).

Comment: I find it weird that you test $conn after you used it...
Usually, I would test if (!$conn) and then use it with $conn->query...
Also, I don't understand why you fetch_assoc and then mysqli_fetch_array.

This line : 
echo "<div id=\"itempicture\"><img src=\"getImage.php?id=."$row['id']".\" width=\"230\" height=\"140\" /></div>";

Should be written like this :
echo "<div id=\"itempicture\"><img src=\"getImage.php?id=".$row['id']."\" width=\"230\" height=\"140\" /></div>";

Comment: You already told that to your while loop, LIMIT 0, 15 - see?

Comment: NOTE: You are not supposed to put your code in the `wamp\www` folder. You have now overwritten the WAMPServer homepage!

Comment: @JulienB. so i should put the "if statement" before the $RESULT right?,

Comment: @Your Common Sense i know i wrote it but still it only run once and it starts on my second row idk why..

Comment: @RiggsFolly thats what i want to do though.... where you think i should put it ?

Comment: @JulienB. because for some reason you have one extra fetch in your code

Comment: Create a Virtual Hosts for all your projects [See this post on the WAMPServer Forum](http://forum.wampserver.com/posting.php?2,moderation,138456) or this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618

Comment: @NicePersonsLiveMore you might start at the 2nd line because you fetch once before your while loop (not sure). As for the if statement, you are testing it after you first used it... So yes, your test should be logically be done before you use it. And FYI, be aware that using LIMIT without ORDER BY might give you unexpected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "<div id=\"itempicture\"><img src=\"getImage.php?id=."$row['id']".\" width=\"230\" height=\"140\" /></div>";
```

You have the `.` after and before `$row`, inside the quotes. They need to be outside of the quotes.

**EDIT:**

So the solution is:

```
echo "<div id=\"itempicture\"><img src=\"getImage.php?id=".$row['id']."\" width=\"230\" height=\"140\" /></div>";
```

Comment: echo "<div id=\"itempicture\"><img src=\"getImage.php?id=.$row['id'].\" width=\"230\" height=\"140\" /></div>";
i wrote this but still i have error can you fix it for me ?

Comment: @NicePersonsLiveMore Dont remove the quotes from the old code. Just move the dots out of the quotation marks.

Comment: thanks! and do you happen to know anyhow why is it start the my loop on the second row? my table has 2 row...

Comment: @NicePersonsLiveMore If you want to get the first 15, just use `LIMIT 15`